# HexColor to HSV conversion Java

Tags: java, colors, hex, awt, hsv

I am looking for a way to convert HexColors to HSV/HSB Model in Java so that I can bifurcate the colors into X Color family where X being(Red,Green etc). I came across the Color Wheel model where Red Color spans a Hue 60 degrees(-30 degree to +30 degrees). So I wanted to convert Hex color to HSB/HSV model and find the Hue which lies in the corresponding range for bifurcation.

I tried using the **java.awt** RGBoHSB method to get the float array with HSB. The Hue value returned from the method does not seem to be in degrees/radians to me hence I am not able to bifurcate. Moreover I want to avoid using the **java.awt** so could someone suggest some alternative method for the conversion of Hex colors to HSV in the format which would solve my problem and I can bifurcate the colors into classes according to color wheel.

Comment: Maybe [HSL Color](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Conversion of Hex to RGB I used

```
 public Color hex2Rgb(String colorStr) {
  return new Color(
          Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 ),
          Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 ),
          Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 ) );
```

}

And for conversion of RGB to HSV in desired format I followed the article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-change-rgb-color-model-hsv-color-model/
. This helped me to separate Color familes on the basis of Color Wheel theory(http://warrenmars.com/visual_art/theory/colour_wheel/evolution/evolution.htm)

PS: This did not use AWT methods